# Time environment variable not working as expected

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I trying to measure time using Windows command line.

```
echo %TIME% & timeout 5 > NUL & echo %TIME%
```

But this command prints two equal timestamps. Why? What I'am doing wrong?
`timeout 5` is just for example.

Comment: Add `setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION`

Comment: `setlocal` has no effect outside of batchfiles.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The interpreter first parses the whole line (replacing both `%time%` with the same value (because same time of parsing)) *before* executing anything. You need [delayed expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30282784/variables-in-batch-not-behaving-as-expected/30284028#30284028) to make it work.

If you need a command line solution:

```
cmd /v /c "echo !time! & timeout 5 & echo !time!"
```

Comment: Please, you are a 34.4k reputation, you flag a duplicate and still answer the question?

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher I answered the question, and then someone notified me of the duplicate, so I flagged it as such. (it's a quite wordy dupe handling batchfiiles (the command line solution is hidden somewhere in the middle), so it isn't very obvious and I guess most newbies wouldn't catch the point, so I left the answer)

Answer (score 1):

This article https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20060823-00/?p=29993 says the ENV variables are expanded at the time the command is read.  Your results would seem to indicate that the entire command line is read/parsed/expanded at once before anything is executed.

Comment: LOL - the very same second `:D`